# how to calculate a transformation matrix based on data obtained from vl_sift?

Tags: matlab, transformation, sift

I have used the SIFT implementation of Andrea Vedaldi, to calculate the sift descriptors of two images in order to align them,

```
   Ia = imread('roofs1.jpg')) ;
   Ib = imread('roofs2.jpg')) ;

   %calculate descriptors

   [fa,da] = vl_sift(im2single(rgb2gray(Ia))) ;
   [fb,db] = vl_sift(im2single(rgb2gray(Ib))) ;
    %matching
   [matches, scores] = vl_ubcmatch(da,db) ;
   [drop, perm] = sort(scores) ;
   matches = matches(:, perm(1:50)) ;
   scores  = scores(perm(1:50))
```

and after I get the keypoints

```
d1=fa(1:2,matches(1,:));
d2=fb(1:2,matches(2,:));
```

Now i want to calculate the transformation matrix M between this two images

```
Pos1=d1';
Pos2=d2';
Pos1(:,3)=1; Pos2(:,3)=1;
M=Pos1'/Pos2';
```

then apply a transformation with a function [affine_warp](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28300-opensurf--including-image-warp-/content/WarpFunctions/affine_warp.m) to get a tranformed image

```
Ia_warped=affine_warp(Ia,M,'bicubic');
```

But in reality i get this result [image: image results]

If someone can help me to identify where's mistake in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ascertain the homography or transformation matrix which maps the points from the first set to the other. This can be done with the [Direct Linear Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_linear_transformation) algorithm which is explained in the book [Multiple View Geometry](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/). Matlab also has a [tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale-using-automated-feature-matching.html?prodcode=IP&language=en).

RANSAC is usually used to rid the set of ouliers, demos of which can be found on the [vlfeat site](http://www.vlfeat.org/applications/sift-mosaic-code.html) and the site of [Peter Kovesi](http://www.peterkovesi.com/matlabfns/Robust/example/index.html) .

Comment: thank you so much for your response , normally this is what I want to do with `M=Pos1'/Pos2'; Ia_warped=affine_warp(Ia,M,'bicubic');` do you have any idea about what i should do ??
unfortunately I can not use RANSAC, because I have to delete the outliers with my own algorithm.

Comment: Applying your proposal with DLT  `M=DLT(Pos1',Pos2');`, I get the same result (white instead of black!!)